# JCodeModel to use in custom maven archetype

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin, maven-archetype

I am new to maven and Jcodemodel. I am trying to create an archetype which will accept the wsdl and generate the code. I need to create java code for implementation class file by implementing the interface. I need to use JCodeModel to generate java code. But I am new to JCode. How to use Jcodemodel inside Maven archetype to generate java code?

Kindly, guide me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maven will build your projects and automate some aspects of managing the builds and the project; but, it will not decide for you what the project does, or how to go about writing the project.

You might need to write Java code that (because you mentioned a WSDL) runs as a web service.  That web service apparently should accept "something" and reply back with "something".  It is a guess (this is a very vague question), that the something it should accept is some sort of description of a Java class, and the something it should reply will be either Java source code, or a compiled java class.

In either case, the project can be managed by Maven, meaning that Maven will compile, test, and package your project.  In certain cases, it will also deploy it (if you configured Maven to do so).

Now if you want Maven to actually accept the WSDL and generate the code, then what Maven will build will be static, meaning that the "generated" code will not be able to change after Maven completes the build.  You can; however, build the "next" version which might change.  If this scenario sounds more like what you had in mind, then your "source" would be a static file, and the "built project" would be the source code or the object code corresponding to the source.

Without more direction, this is probably the best guide you are going to get.  It is just too vague a question, covering too much ground to say much definitively.  You also seem to lack a lot of knowledge in a lot key places simultaneously; perhaps the best solution is to identify what you will likely need to brush up on, order those by "what needs what" and start with the element that depends on nothing else.